# How to make tab buttons width flexible - ionic 2

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic2, tabs

Is there any way to make the width of tabs buttons flexible ?

for example this my normal tabs

[image]

I want to make the tabs width such as this image

[image]

I could show the full text by this css code

```
.tab-button {
   min-width: fit-content;
}
```

but the result was such as the this picture

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Maybe try something like this:

```css
.tabs{
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.single-tab{
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="single-tab">
    Tab1
  </div>
  <div class="single-tab">
    Tab2222222
  </div>
  <div class="single-tab">
    Tab3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: More details please, i checked all possible solutions but no luck